# grey out preprocessors like as ifdef/def in emacs

Tags: emacs, hide

I'm looking for a way to grey out ifdef in emacs rather than hiding/folding with ...(3dots) as Source insight/Visual Studio does.

Please share your tip if you know

Answer (score 3):

There is `hideif` package in the standard Emacs library. It's activated by `hide-ifdef-mode`.  You can set `hide-ifdef-shadow` to `t` to use color (defined by face `hide-ifdef-shadow`) instead of hiding the piece of code.

There is more information about it on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef).